# Select Distinct value SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have table like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
id | title | image  | name |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | xyzab | so.jpg | googl |
2  | acbde | am.jpg | artic |
3  | xyzab | pp.jpg | other |
```

i want to select unique or distinct title with it's image and name also.
DO not want to repeat the values. I use this this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT title,image,name,id FROM `some_table`
```

but this is not working fine

**NOTE**: The OP is working with MySQL

Comment: What version of SQL are you running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `DISTINCT` will ensure no 2 records have **all** columns matching, so this *is* working correctly.

If you want to return unique titles, you need to decide what image and name would be returned.

You could use a group by with an aggregate function to do this. For example:

```
SELECT title, MIN(image), MIN(name), MIN(id)
FROM `some_table`
GROUP BY title
```

But it depends on what results you are after...

Comment: Becaus it's not working right. When I execute this on my test table I get the following: `acbde |am.jpg | artic | 2` `xyzab | pp.jpg | googl | 1` The entry with id 1 has the image `so.jpg` and not `pp.jpg`. I don't think this is desired effect?

Comment: OP didn't specify what they wanted to do with the extra columns. What if I had used `SUM` instead of `MIN`? Then you wouldn't see data matching any existing columns. I just chose a random aggregate function as an example, the data is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the WINNER... in other words if there is a duplicate title but differening data in other columns you need to pick one...

For example you could try this.

```
select * from 'some_table' where id in (select min(id) from 'some_table' group by title)
```

Comment: sorry while I was writing my answer another got it... I'll leave it as it shows you another way to go after the same idea

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is not applied to the one field after the keyword, but for fields in your select statement. What you're looking for is `GROUP BY`:

`SELECT title,image,name,id FROM some_table GROUP BY title`

Comment: Have you tested executing a query like that? You'll get an error.

Comment: It'll be something along the lines of image,name,id need to be in an aggregate function if not in the Group by clause.

Comment: Youre grouping by title. So that means one title per record. If the `title` is `xyzab`, what will `image` be?

Comment: I have rebuilt the table as Basic Bridge wrote and executed my query. No error

Comment: I'd be interested to see the results.

Comment: Result is 

`acbde | am.jpg | artic | 2`

`xyzab | so.jpg | googl | 1`

Comment: I have tested in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and your answer does not execute. The error is `Column 'some_table.image' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: That's strange... Works in terminal on my MySQL server.